# Erro ao tentar inserir dados ao PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

Estou com problemas para inserir informações ao BD. Acredito que o erro esteja na camada DAO mais especificamente na função inserir. Vocês poderiam me ajudar a encontrar esse erro?

CONNECTIONFACTORY

```
package DAO;
import java.sql.Statement;  
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionFactory {

    public static Connection  getConnectionFactory() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{


            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/topografiaJava";  
            String usuario = "postgres";  
            String senha = "1";  

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  

            Connection con;  

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);  

            System.out.println("Conexão realizada com sucesso.");  

           Statement st1;  
           st1 = con.createStatement();
           return con;

    }
}
```

Classe PessoaDAO

```
public class PessoaDAO {
    private Connection conn;

 private Pessoa resultSet2Model(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Pessoa p;
     p = new Pessoa(rs.getInt("id"),
             rs.getString("nome"),
             rs.getString("matricula"),
             rs.getString("setor"),
             rs.getString("login"),
             rs.getString("senha"),
             rs.getString("email"));
        return p; 
    }

    public Pessoa inserir(Pessoa p) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
         PreparedStatement st1=null;
         this.conn = new ConnectionFactory().getConnectionFactory();   
         st1 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into pessoa set (id, nome, matricula, setor, login, senha, email) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
         st1.setInt(1, 2);
         st1.setString(2, p.getNome());
         st1.setString (3, p.getMatricula());
         st1.setString(4, p.getSetor());
         st1.setString(5, p.getLogin());
         st1.setString(6,p.getSenha());
         st1.setString(7, p.getEmail());
         ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery();
         rs1.next();
         st1.execute();
         return p;
            }
```

Erro:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "set"
>   Posição: 20
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2422)
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2167)
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
>   at DAO.PessoaDAO.inserir(PessoaDAO.java:55)
>   at DAO.TestaDAO.main(TestaDAO.java:28)
> C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> Java returned: 1
> FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
> ```

Comment: E qual é o erro? Onde está a pilha de erro? Adicione isso na pergunta.

Comment: Acredito que não tenha aquele  `set` em `insert into pessoa set`.

Comment: Removi o set e gerou o erro:Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Nenhum resultado foi retornado pela consulta.

Comment: Ai já  é um erro completamente diferente da pergunta feita, o erro da pergunta foi respondido.

Comment: @elbenevides Nesse caso você deveria abrir uma nova pergunta com o novo problema. Btw, você sempre pode marcar uma resposta como correta nas suas perguntas, é só usar o **V** do lado esquerdo da resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe do `insert` está incorreta. O erro diz exatamente qual parte está errada.

> ERROR: syntax error **at or near "set"**

Está assim

```
st1 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into pessoa set (...) values (...)");
```

e deveria ser sem a palavra `SET`

```
st1 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into pessoa (...) values (...)");
```