# Como verificar se usuário já foi cadastrado no banco de dados?

Tags: java, jdbc

Como posso verificar se usuário já está cadastrado? Por exemplo,
ao cadastrar um usuário verificar se o login já foi salvo no BD.
A DAO ficou assim:

```
public boolean validarLogin (String login) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    boolean existe = false;
    Pessoa p =null;
    PreparedStatement st=null;
    this.conn=new ConnectionFactory().getConnectionFactory();
    String sql = ("SELECT login FROM pessoa WHERE login = ?");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        String loginBanco = rs.getString("login");
        if (loginBanco.equals("login")){
            existe = true;
            st.close();
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário" + login + "existente");
        }
    }
    return existe;
}
```

O que vocês acham, é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [PreparedStatment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) quando sua *query* tiver `"?"`

```
PreparedStatement statement =  this.conn.prepareStatement("SELECT login FROM pessoa WHERE login = ?");    
statement.setString(1, login);    
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

No seu código, você já está utilizando, porém está tentando executar a *query* em uma variável nula.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código tem alguns problemas. Primeiro, não misture lógica de visualização `JOptionPane` com lógica de banco de dados.

Considerando que a sua classe `ConnectionFactory` é a [**desta questão**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276445/132), ela têm sérios problemas no gerenciamento da conexão. Vou consertá-la com base no que fiz [**nessa outra resposta aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258256/132) e também [**nessa**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/275323/132):

```
package dao;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public final class ParametrosDeConexao {
    private final String url;
    private final String usuario;
    private final String senha;

    public ParametrosDeConexao(String url, String usuario, String senha) {
        this.url = url;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
    }
}
```

Com isso, seu código fica que nem esse abaixo. Observe que o campo `CONECTAR` representa o que era sua classe `ConnectionFactory`:

```
private static final ParametrosDeConexao CONECTAR =
        new ParametrosDeConexao( 
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/topografiaJava",
                "postgres",
                "1");

private static final String LOGIN_SQL =
        "SELECT login FROM pessoa WHERE login = ?";

public boolean validarLogin(String login) throws SQLException {
    try (
        Connection c = CONECTAR.conectar();
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(LOGIN_SQL)
    ) {
        ps.setString(1, login);
        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
            return rs.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Observe como o método `validarLogin(String)` ficou bastante enxuto. Para isso:

- Lembre-se de usar o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132). A menos que você esteja trabalhando com o Java 6 ou anterior, **NUNCA** deixe de utilizá-lo com `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` ou `ResultSet`.
- Lembre-se de preencher os parâmetros do `PreparedStatement` adequadamente (com o `setString(1, login)` neste caso.
- O `return rs.next();` vai dar o `true` ou `false` que você quer dependendo se há ou não resultado no `ResultSet`. No seu caso, é desnecessário ler esse resultado.
- O `Class.forName` não é mais necessário. Veja mais sobre isso [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242765/132).