# Como faço para validar login quando o usuário mudar de campo?

Tags: java

Como posso verificar se um login já foi cadastrado? Abaixo segue trecho de uma tentativa que fiz. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Esse é um trecho da camada DAO.

```
public boolean validarLogin () throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String login = null;
    this.conn=new ConnectionFactory().getConnectionFactory();
    boolean testa;
    String LOGIN_SQL ="SELECT login FROM pessoa WHERE login = ?";
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(LOGIN_SQL);
    st.setString(1, login);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()){
        testa = rs.getBoolean(LOGIN_SQL);
    }
    else {
        testa = false;
    }
    return testa;
}
```

Aqui é o codigo que consta no evento da VIEW.

```
 PessoaDAO pDAO = new PessoaDAO();
   boolean login = false;
    try {
        login = pDAO.validarLogin();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(cadastrar_pessoa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(cadastrar_pessoa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println(login);
```

Estou estudando por conta própria e estou tendo alguns problemas de iniciante, como vocês podem ver. (rs)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276585/como-verificar-se-usu%C3%A1rio-j%C3%A1-foi-cadastrado-no-banco-de-dados

Comment: É necessário passar um parâmetro para `validarLogin`. Ex: `public boolean(String login)`; Depois remover `String login = null` e por fim `pDAO.validarLogin("seu-login");`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Agradeço a ajuda.